# IzPack ChmodInstallerListener.jar

Tags: chmod, izpack

I am trying to use IzPack to grant permissions to a directory when it is installed.

In my install file, I have a listener set up as:

```
<listeners>
    <listener installer="ChmodInstallerListener">
    </listener>
</listeners>
```

My pack contains the following:

```
    <pack name="ApacheDS" required="yes" preselected="yes"
        installGroups="New Application">
        <description>apacheds install</description>
        <file src="@{apacheds.dir}" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" >
            <additionaldata key="permission.dir" value="775"/>
        </file>
    </pack>
```

Every time I run my ant script, I get a message saying that my CustomAction jar file is not found. I would think that this jar file would be standard with IzPack. Do I need to write a java class for this? Where should I call the jar file?

Answer (score 3):

Best workaround:

Use the executable tag in the pack. I am able to distribute the .sh files as executable with a little bit of code.

First: 
call the resource in the pack

```
<file src="@{MyProject.dir}/bin/startup.sh" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/PROJECT/bin/" />
```

Next make it executable (also in the pack)

```
<executable 
targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/PROJECT/bin/startup.sh" 
stage="never" keep="true" >
    <os family="mac" />
    <args>
        <arg value="754" />
        <arg value="@{MyProject.dir}/bin/*.sh" />
    </args>
</executable>
```

The first arg changes the permissions to -rwrx-xr--x

The second calls the file to be changed.

The file will now have executable permissions when the user runs the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a copy of the ChmodInstallerListener.class file in the IzPack bin under com/myCompany/tools/install/listener. I converted it into a jar file, and stored it in bin/customActions/ but my program still can't recognize it.

I keep getting the same warning: CustomAction jar not found: bin/customActions/ChmodInstallerListener.jar.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?